# Use awk to replace value from column A with value from column B

Tags: pandas, shell, awk

I'm very new to coding so I am here seeking some help. I have the table below, and I need to do as follow:
Every time that 
`[All_SNPs]<[Informative_SNPs]`
I need to replace negative numbers or number=0 in [All_SNPs] with the values in [Informative_SNPs]. I have tried with awk but I can't get my head around this. Thank you if you can help.

Input

```
ID Informative_SNPs All_SNPs
1 13 0
2 29 -27
3 15 18
4 10 0
5 11 -850
6 25 37
```

Output

```
ID Informative_SNPs All_SNPs
1 13 13
2 29 29
3 15 18
4 10 10
5 11 11
6 25 37
```

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: You might want to turn off the alpha channel on that image and make the background opaque white for us who use dark mode on SO. ;)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk 'NR>1 && ($3<=0 || $3<$2) {$3=$2}1' file
```

Output:

```
ID Informative_SNPs All_SNPs
1 13 13
2 29 29
3 15 18
4 10 10
5 11 11
6 25 37
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! I will follow your precious advise next time I post here. Thanks @Cyrus